# CamanJS - Mobile - Blank Canvas

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, canvas, camanjs

I am having problems running the CamanJS script on mobile devices, i.e. iPad and iPhone's Safari / Chrome, and I've been trying to resolve it for days.

The test script is very simple:
1) Accepts browser file selection of image
2) Gets the image source using FileData, then drawing it into a canvas, then instantiate a Caman("#sample") object
3) Run some filter (either within onLoad of that image, or manually by clicking a button)

It works perfectly fine on all desktop browsers and the filters are also successfully applied, but when I try it on mobile devices like iOS Safari, the moment I try to instantiate the Caman object, my existing canvas #sample goes blank and reverts to the original canvas default background color, with no image loaded at all. I've tried instantiating the Caman object before image is drawn on canvas, image onLoad, or on demand after the canvas image is successfully drawn, but the end result is still the same - the canvas goes blank.

Below is my sample code, can someone please advise? Thank you for your kind assistance.

```
<script>
var caman = null;

function handleUpload(evt) {
    var target = (evt.target) ? evt.target : evt.srcElement;
    var files = target.files; // FileList object
    var field = target.id;
    var curCount = target.id.replace(/\D+/, "");

    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
            return function(e) {
                renderImage(e.target.result);
            };
        })(f);

        reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
}

function renderImage(imagedata) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("sample");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    // Render Preview
    var previewImage = new Image();
    previewImage.src = imagedata;
    previewImage.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(previewImage, 0, 0, previewImage.width, previewImage.height);
        caman = Caman("#sample", function () { this.sunrise().render(); });
    };
}

function testProcess() {
    //caman = Caman("#sample", function () { this.sunrise().render(); }); 
    if (caman) { 
        caman.sunrise().render();
    }
}

</script>


<form>
<input id="photo" name="photo" value="" type=file size="30" maxlength="50">
</form>

<canvas id="sample" width=300 height=300 style="background-color: #aaaaaa;"></canvas>

<br><br><a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="testProcess();">Test Process</a><br><br>

<script>
document.getElementById('photo').addEventListener('change', handleUpload, false);
</script>
```

Comment: I found a dirty patch to comment out the hiDPI ratio section for retina display, which made it work, but I'm not sure if it is a good solution and if it'd affect other functionality.. basically just comment out the following JS section:

      if (ratio !== 1) { 
          ....
      }

Even though it works now, it's not stable on mobile browsers if I process camera photos, it appears to crash the browsers including Safari, perhaps due to too much memory needed to process hi-res pics. 

Any ideas on how to efficiently process them?

Comment: Did you find any solution now?

Comment: Unfortunately not at that time, so I did not use the module. You may want to check their latest version and see if the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem: worked on Chrome and Safari on my Mac, but did not work on Chrome or Safari on the iPhone 5s running iOS7. I solved by adding the data-caman-hidpi-disabled attribute to my canvas tag.

Try this:

```
<canvas id="sample" width=300 height=300 style="background-color: #aaaaaa;" data-caman-hidpi-disabled="true"></canvas>
```

According to the CamanJS website:

> If a HiDPI display is detected, CamanJS will automatically switch to
>   the HiDPI version if available unless you force disable it with the
>   data-caman-hidpi-disabled attribute.

http://camanjs.com/guides/#BasicUsage

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing the tips, I'll test it out! Do you know how best to efficiently run filters on mobile camera photos? It appears to be quite laggy. I'd like to use it in conjunction with Cordova, or do you know of any good Cordova image filter plugins that are efficient and versatile?

Comment: The more filters you add, the slower the process will be. I don't think there's any way around that. 

I added a loader animation while the filters were processing.

Comment: Thanks for this! Couldn't figure out why my canvas was blank, turns out HiDPI can also be detected when you use a browser's Zoom functionality to zoom <100% on a page.